# How to store Nokogiri xpath in MySQL

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

MySQL column (`product_path`) has value `//*[(@id=\"scroller\")]/li/*/a`. Using it with Nokogiri throws `Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError: Invalid expression:`  Whats wrong.

```
require 'mysql2'
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection( 
  :adapter => "mysql2",
  :host => "localhost",
  ...
)

class MyTable < ActiveRecord::Base
end

@s = MyTable.first

#...Looks like backward slash is escaped automatically by mysql
@s.product_path #=> "//*[(@id=\\\"scroller\\\")]/li/*/a"

p = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@s.url))

#all variations below throw invalid expression error
p.search(@s.product_path).count
p.search("#{@s.product_path").count
p.xpath(@s.product_path).count

#But this works flawlessly.
p.search("//*[(@id=\"scroller\")]/li/*/a").count #=> works fine.
```

**Update**

I tried this and it worked.

```
a = '//*[(@id="scroller")]/li/*/a'
p.search(a).count
```

The additional back slashes seem to create the issue. How do I get rid of them?

Comment: `puts` the `product_path` to see what it is, `inspect` will escape embedded quotes and backslashes and just confuse you. And what does `product_path` look like *before* you put it in the database? Where does it come from? Why use double quotes around a string that doesn't use interpolation and has embedded double quotes?

Comment: `product_path` is entered manually by me.

Comment: But how is it entered? What does it look like when you enter it?

Comment: I enter them using Toad for MySQL and when I do it looks like this `//*[(@id=\"scroller\")]/li/*/a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're entering the XPath expression as:

```
//*[(@id=\"scroller\")]/li/*/a
```

Note the escaped double quotes. Then you get this Ruby string:

```
"//*[(@id=\\\"scroller\\\")]/li/*/a"
```

but that's `inspect` output so some things will be escaped. If you `puts` that string, you'll get:

```
//*[(@id=\"scroller\")]/li/*/a
```

which is exactly the string you put in. But, your XPath expression shouldn't have `\"` around the attribute value, it should just have `"`.

So you're entering invalid the wrong XPath expressions, getting those expressions back out of the database, and wondering why they're wrong. Fix your input procedure to not over escape things and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveRecord::sanitize_sql` method maybe useful here, but it's protected so before saving xpaths to db try:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send :sanitize_sql, your_xpath
```

Comment: I enter these paths manually to DB (as they are a finite set)